# Objective-C generic getter methods

Tags: objective-c, getter-setter

I need to overwrite the getter method of multiple properties using the getter attribute when I declare my property like the following. I would like the getter of all my properties to be the same method as the code to get those three properties is the same.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong, getter=getObject) (NSString*) obj1;
@property (nonatomic,strong, getter=getObject) (NSString*) obj2;
@property (nonatomic,strong, getter=getObject) (NSString*) obj3;
```

Although, I would need, in my getObject method, to know which property is currently being asked. Is is possible in the implementation of the getObject method to know which object is currently being asked? I would like the following %@ code to return either obj1, obj2 or obj3.

```
-(NSString*) getObject{ 

   NSLog(@"the property requested is: %@", ?????)

}
```

Any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks a lot!
Renaud

Comment: seems kinda strange: why would one use the same getter for diffrent objects? how do i select which object i want?

Comment: Why you wanna write the custom getter methods? Is it necessary? I mean just use the default getters/setters using @synthesize. or if there is anything specifically needed then clear up please!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

When you define your `getter` method, the compiler is going to translate requests to `myObject.obj3` into simply `[myObject getObject]`. At that point, you have lost the information about which property was invoked.

You should just define a different getter for each property, and any shared or duplicated code can go into a private method like `getObject:`:

```
- (NSString *)getObject:(NSString *)propertyName {
    // ...
}

- (NSString *)obj1 {
    return [self getObject:@"obj1"];
}

- (NSString *)obj2 {
    return [self getObject:@"obj2"];
}

// ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I would have like to avoid the cut and paste because I have a lot of properties defined in that object and they might change through the project but if it is not possible to avoid it...